# Statements in the Condition of a While Loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Say I have a collection of things that can be accessed with `TheCollection.GetByID(long)`, but there's no way for me to get the length of the thing in advance. I'd like to set up a while loop to go through each one.

Clearly I could do something like this:

```
var iter = 0; var thing = TheCollection.GetByID(iter);
while (thing != null) {
    dealWithTheThing(thing);
    iter++;
    thing = TheCollection.GetByID(iter);
}
```

But I'd prefer to tidy it up by putting the modifications in the constructor, and be able to get something like this:

```
var iter = 0; var thing;
while ((thing = TheCollection.GetByID(iter++)) != null) {
    dealWithTheThing(thing);
}
```

Is this, or something like it, possible?

Comment: Why don't you try it? It will work: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/nBhAA/3/

Comment: I tried it and couldn't get it to work, so I asked this to check if I had the right idea. Now that I know that wasn't the problem, I can see it's not working due to the contents of the collection. Thanks!

Comment: It can be slower putting **expressions** in a while condition rather than the following block, but usually not significantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your example is fine. You can have assignments within a condition, and the style is perfectly clear (at least to me).

Comment: Thanks! Knowing that this wasn't a problem helped me find the actual problem in my code, and leaves me much happier with the look of the result!

Answer (score 1):

While using the assignment operator in the condition for a loop looks pretty, it can be cause confusion for others as it is easy to typo the `==` to `=` ([read more: search for "Assignment Expressions"](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html))

<strike>Having given you the warning, I find the following more readable:</strike>

```
var iter = 0; var thing;
while (thing = TheCollection.GetByID(iter++) && thing != null) {
    dealWithTheThing(thing);
}
```

Comment: I disagree, for a couple of reasons, not least that this changes the nature of his loop. Your assignment statement will be `false` for anything falsey (so that's `""`, `false`, `0`, etc.), whereas many of those things are `!= null`. So you'll break out of the loop on different conditions, since you're using `&&`. You're actually testing `thing` twice, and the first test is fairly well hidden. This is less, not more, readable than the OP's original. If you *really* want to do this, you could use the comma operator. It doesn't improve readability either, but at least it doesn't introduce issues.

Comment: @TJCrowder: I was under the impression (somehow) that an assignment always returned true, regardless of the value assigned. You are, of, course, correct :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's good that this discussion pointed that out (about the boolean values of assignments) as it's not something I explicitly knew beforehand.

Comment: @Matt: Actually I was both right and wrong, the `&&` has higher precedence than the `=` and so the loop was actually `while (thing = (TheCollection.GetByID(iter++) && thing != null))`, which is even less obvious. :-)

Comment: @TJCrowder: Definitely best to avoid this construction if it confuses everyone :P. I've been using this approach for *years*... thankfully only with truthy values, which must be why I've been living in a bubble for so long!

Comment: Crikey, that last thing looks dangerous :P